# vraptor/weld project only works on mac

Tags: linux, macos, jakarta-ee, weld, vraptor

the very same codebase works with no errors on the same tomcat version, just java version remains as the main difference.

This stacktrace [ http://pastebin.com/cPCTJGw4 ] is all that i got when i tried to run the project on fedora with java 7 (openjdk-1.7 from fedora repository).

I've already tried to change vraptor version, but it was useless.

Since my production environment does not run mac os, i need it working on fedora linux as well.

Any guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds to be some conflict in the project dependencies.

```
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found
```

Are you using maven?

If so, I'd try to run `mvn clean` before compiling it again.

Comment: Hello, i tried to clean but the error remain. Here's complete stacktrace i got after mvn clean, after tomcat clean, et all. http://pastebin.com/zeR8VSvY